# How to get path of thumbnail from mediastore in reasonable time to load images in a gridview?

Tags: android, thumbnails, mediastore

I'm trying to show **thumbnails of images** from sdcard in a `gridview`. I'm using `universal image loader` and image loading is takes reasonable time.

**My problem is:** trying to get all paths for the thumbnails takes too much time and causes lag on the gridview scroll. If i try ro read all paths ahead of the loading images then it takes 10 seconds (500 images on S5). I see a lot of app already solved this problem and it seems i am making some fundemantal mistakes here, yet i couldn't find what it is.

PS: I got this code from an answer on stackoverflow and i think my problem is not related to code but it is related with my approach to the problem.
Here is the code:

```
public static String getThumbnailPath(Activity activity, long imageId) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(activity, uri, proj, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();



    cursor.moveToFirst();

    String result="";
    cursor = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.queryMiniThumbnail(activity.getContentResolver(), imageId,
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        result = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA));
        cursor.close();
    }

    result = "file://" +  result;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Use pagination? ie load only a few articles at a time. Not all of them. You can google how to do it

Comment: Please post relevant source code.

Comment: I am loading only few of them when they are reqired to shown but then it causes lags when user scrolls the gridview.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at smoothie by Lucas Rocha. It is a library project for fast scrolling listviews and gridviews. I use it in my app Playlist Manager.  Easy to implement.